# replace html element value

Tags: html

Im trying to prompt for a value that will replace the value for "data-amount", How would you go about doing this?

```
<html>

<body>

<a href="http://google.com/" class="dwolla_button" data-name="Lease" data-desc="Payments" data-amount="4" data-shipping="0" data-tax="0" data-guest-checkout="true" data-key="xxxxx">Bank </a>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dwolla.com/scripts/button.min.js"> </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to replace using javascript in this manner

```
<script>
document.getElementByClass("dwolla_button").data-amount="43";
</script>
```

and have thought about using jquery like this but wasn't sure how to load jquery in the first place

```
$("a").attr("data_amount", "43")
```

Any ideas?

the whole code that ive tried fully is

```
<html>
  <body>

    <a href="http://249lease.webs.com/" class="dwolla_button" data-name="Lease" data-desc="Payments" data-amount="5" data-shipping="0" data-tax="0" data-guest-checkout="true" data-key="sHqCOc31Vh3JiAsPhBfEk5f4D9bAWKLzwaT06ah3Aw65i0gkZl">Bank Account (25¢)</a>


<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementByClass("dwolla_button")[0].setAttribute("data-amount", "43");
</script>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dwolla.com/scripts/button.min.js"> </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple JS solution is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dwolla_button")[0].setAttribute("data-amount", "43");
```

Which would work if the `dwolla_button` is the first (or only) `dwolla_button` in the page.

Comment: Yay for vanilla JS (just saw the OP may not have jQuery already loaded)

Comment: how would i write this into my script i tried adding this 

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementByClass("dwolla_button")[0].setAttribute("data-amount", "43");
</script>

Comment: That should work. But you have to make sure that there's only one `<a>` with the class `dwolla_button` in the page, or that the one you are targeting is the first `dwolla_button` in the page. Do you have a specific page you can link to, or can you give me the entire HTML file?

Comment: Is it still not working? Try to put your custom script after the dwolla script. In other words, put it right before the `</body>` tag, to make sure the other script does not override yours.

Comment: Right. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

if you already have jQuery, [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is what you're looking for:

```
$(".dwolla_button").data("amount", 43)
```

it will use HTML 5's `data` properties where supported, and its own implementation 
in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

include this script that google provides for loading jquery :-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```